# Run a command against multiple directories with slightly different names

Tags: command-line, server, directory-structure

I want to run a command to delete backups so that I can reduce disk usage. Not sure how, but `*` represents all the directories under the `sites` directory

```
sudo rm -r sites/*/private/backups/*
```

My directory structure would be as given below:

```
ls sites 

sites/hello/private/backups/
sites/world/private/backups/
sites/hello_world.txt
```

This is not working

Comment: "This is not working" is not a good error description. What happens and what would you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This assumes that you use the convention of adding the `~` suffix to backups. If you use something else, you need to change the `find` argument accordingly. For example, if you use, If you instead of something like `.bak`, the `*~` should instead be `.bak`.

Try this:

First, run

```
sudo find /sites -type f -name '*~'
```

and look through the output. If you are comfortable with deleting the files in the listing, reenter the command, but pipe the output to `rm` as in

```
sudo find /sites -type f -name '*~' -print0 | xargs -0 /usr/bin/rm
```

This will cause the shell to execute `rm PATHNAME` on each PATHNAME in the list.

The `*` character in `bash` is a wildcard character. It will match one or more instances of almost any character. The most notable exception to this rule is the `/` character, which is why it only matches one directory at a time in your example. Use `**` to match any number of directories in a pathname.

EDIT:

Just noticed that you listed your directory as `sites/...` and not `/sites/...`. You need to be sure that the first parameter passed to `find` is the **full path** to the directory. Otherwise, it will just return an error.

EDIT 2:

While I was fixing the second command, I realized that that `find` itself can do what rm is doing but without the need to make any extra calls. This should work, but I still wouldn't advise doing it without first running the top version to see exactly what will be deleted. The command is

```
sudo find /sites -type f -name '*~' -delete
```

As a final tip, if you use `find` a lot, and have system backups, you see your output overtaken by duplicates. If so, look up the `-prune` option. It will keep anything matching its associated argument out of the output.

Comment: @steeldriver thx... again. I was thinking it read from stdin when with no arg. I checked everything up to there on my terminal, just because I didn't want anyone deleting their filesystems on my account. Now I wosh Id have made a dummy file or two. My mistake. Fixing it now. thanks again.